# How to execute an application existing in each specific folder of a directory tree on a file in same folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have some folders with different names. Each folder has a specific structure as listed below:

- **Folder1**

  - **Contents**

    - **x64**

      - Folder1.aaxplugin
      - TransVST_Fixer.exe
- **Folder 2**

  - **Contents**

    - **x64**

      - Folder 2.aaxplugin
      - TransVST_Fixer.exe

There are two files within each subfolder `x64`. One file has the same name as the folder two folder levels above. The other file is an .exe file whose name is the same in all folders.

Now I need to run file with file extension `aaxplugin` on each specific .exe file. It would be obviously very time consuming opening each and every single folder and drag & drop each file on .exe to run it on this file.

That's why I am trying to create a batch script to save some time.

I looked for solutions here on Stack Overflow. The only thing I have found so far was a user saying this: When I perform a drag & drop, the process 'fileprocessor.exe' is executed. When I try to launch this exe, though, CMD returns error ('not recognized or not batch file' stuff).

How can I do this?

---

**UPDATE 12/22/2015**

I used first a batch file with following line to copy the executable into `x64` subfolder of `Folder1`.

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\Users\Davide\Desktop\test\Folder1\*") do ( copy "C:\Program Files\Sugar Bytes\TransVST\TransVST_Fixer.exe" "%%a\x64\" 2> nul )
```

After asking here, I tried the following script:

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s x64\*.aaxplugin') do "%%~dpFTransVST_Fixer.exe" "%%F"
```

Unfortunately, the output is as following

```
C:\Users\Davide\Desktop>for /F "delims=" %F in ('dir /b /s x64\*.aaxplugin') do "%~dpFTransVST_Fixer.exe" "%F"
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Can you provide more context on the end goal here?  Why are you dragging & dropping these files?  What does the exe do?

Comment: The drag and drop is needed to launch the exe. When I drag & drop a file over the exe, I am passing the path of the file to be processed. The exe creates an output file with the same ext of the original one.

Comment: So let's see if I have this right.  You want a bat file that lists all the executables in a folder and then calls them individually, passing in a folder to each.  Perhaps something like `file1.exe folder1` `file2.exe folder2` and `file3.exe folder3`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear, but it seems, something like this should work:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s X64\*.ext') do "%%~dpfMyExe.exe" "%%f"
```

Maybe you have to change directory to each folder (depends on your .exe):

```
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /B /ad') do (
    pushd "%%d"
    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b "contents\x64\*.ext"') do (
        cd Contents\x64
        MyExe.exe "%%f"
    )
    popd
)
```

Assuming:

- The Directory structure is fixed and the files are indeed in a subfolder `contents\X64\`.
- MyExe.exe is the same (name) in every folder.
- There is only one file *.ext in every folder.

Comment: Your assumptions seem to be correct. I am going to test your code now. I am a noob BTW, so please forgive me if I ask you simple stuff. I'll be in touch soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\test" %%F in (*.aaxplugin) do (
    set "FilePath=%%~dpF"
    if not "!FilePath:\x64\=!" == "!FilePath!" "%ProgramFiles%\Sugar Bytes\TransVST\TransVST_Fixer.exe" "%%F"
)
endlocal
```

The command **FOR** with option`/R` searches recursive in all directories of directory `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\test` being expanded on your machine to `C:\Users\Davide\Desktop` for files with file extension `aaxplugin`. The loop variable `F` contains on each loop run the name of the found file with full path without surrounding double quotes.

The drive and path of each found file is assigned to environment variable `FilePath`.

Next a case-sensitive string comparison is done between file path with all occurrences of string `\x64\` case-insensitive removed with unmodified file path.

Referencing value of environment variable `FilePath` must be done here using delayed expansion because being defined and evaluated within a block defined with `(` ... `)`. Otherwise command processor would expand `%FilePath%` already on parsing the entire block resulting in a syntax error on execution because string substitution is not possible as no environment variable `FilePath` defined above body block of **FOR** loop.

The strings are **not** equal if path of file contains a folder with name `x64`. This means on provided folder structure that the file is in folder `x64` and not somewhere else and therefore the application is executed next from its original location to fix the found *.aaxplugin file.

The line with **IF** is for the folder structure example:

```
if not "C:\Users\Davide\Desktop\test\Folder1\Contents" == "C:\Users\Davide\Desktop\test\Folder1\Contents\x64\"
if not "C:\Users\Davide\Desktop\test\Folder 2\Contents" == "C:\Users\Davide\Desktop\test\Folder 2\Contents\x64\"
```

So for both *.aaxplugin files the condition is **true** because the compared strings are not identical

Also possible would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /A-D /B /S "%USERPROFILE%\test\*.aaxplugin" 2^>nul') do (
    set "FilePath=%%~dpF"
    if not "!FilePath:\x64\=!" == "!FilePath!" "%ProgramFiles%\Sugar Bytes\TransVST\TransVST_Fixer.exe" "%%F"
)
endlocal
```

But command **DIR** is not really necessary as it can be seen on first provided code.

But if the application `TransVST_Fixer.exe` for some unknown reason does its job right only with directory of file being also the current directory, the following batch code could be used instead of first code using the commands **pushd** and **popd**:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R "%USERPROFILE%\test" %%F in (*.aaxplugin) do (
    set "FilePath=%%~dpF"
    echo !FilePath!
    if /I "!FilePath:~-5!" == "\x64\" (
        pushd "%%~dpF"
        "%ProgramFiles%\Sugar Bytes\TransVST\TransVST_Fixer.exe" "%%~nxF"
        popd
    )
)
endlocal
```

There is one more difference in comparison to first code. Now the last 5 characters of path of file are compared case-insensitive with the string `\x64\`. Therefore the file must be really inside a folder with name `x64` or `X64`. A folder with name `x64` or `X64` anywhere else in path of file does not result anymore in a **true** state for the condition as in first two batch codes.

But if for some unknown reason it is really necessary to run the application in same folder as the found *.aaxplugin and the directory of the file must be the current directory, the following batch code could be used:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R "%USERPROFILE%\test" %%# in (*.aaxplugin) do (
    set "FilePath=%%~dp#"
    if /I "!FilePath:~-5!" == "\x64\" (
        pushd "%%~dp#"
        "%%~dp#TransVST_Fixer.exe" "%%~nx#"
        popd
    )
)
endlocal
```

The path of the file referenced with `%%~dpF` always ends with a backslash which is the reason why there is no backslash left of `TransVST_Fixer.exe` (although command processor could handle also file with with two backslashes in path).

In batch code above character `#` is used as loop variable because `%%~dp#TransVST_Fixer.exe` is easier to read in comparison to `%%~dpFTransVST_Fixer.exe`. It is more clear for a human with using `#` as loop variable where the reference to loop variable ends and where name of application begins. For the command processor it would not make a difference if loop variable is `#` or upper case `F`.

A lower case `f` would work here also as loop variable, but is in general problematic as explained on [Modify variable within loop of batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34188225/3074564).

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the script I created for doing so, hope it works for you

```
for /d %%d IN (./*) do (cd "%%d/Contents/x64" & "../../../TransVST_Fixer.exe" "%%d" & cd "/Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Avid\Audio\Plug-Ins")
```

Please note that I placed the fixer inside the root folder so I just have to copy it once. You have to place it inside your root folder and execute it. What it does:

1. iterate over each folder
2. for each one it enters /Contents/x64, executes the fixer (wich is 3 levels above) and after that returns to the original folder.

If you have your plugins in a different folder, you just have to change this part replacing the path for the one you have your plugins in.

```
cd "/Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Avid\Audio\Plug-Ins"
```

REMEMBER to place the script on that folder. For this example I place my script on the folder "/Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Avid\Audio\Plug-Ins" and run it (as a .bat).

PS: the fixer will place the fixed plugins in "C:\Users\Public\modified" (just read the screen while executing, it gives you the new files path. If you want to move them to the right path, you can execute this from the new files path ("C:\Users\Public\modified")

```
for %%d IN (*.aaxplugin) do (mkdir "%%d_temp/Contents\x64" & move "%%d" "%%d_temp/Contents\x64/%%d" & rename "%%d_temp" "%%d")
```

with that, I iterate over every plugin and create a folder with the same name (I create _temp because of name colision, after moving the file I rename it to the correct one), also with the subfolder "/Contents/x64", and move the plugin inside. Once donde, you can just take the resulting folders and place them in their correct path.

Hope it works, for me it works like a charm.